# PXE Booting Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, pxe

Now that the alternate CD has been axed, how can I obtain the PXE boot files formerly found in netboot?

Comment: That's the network iso/ tar. I want to create a small local installer with 12.10, about the size of the previous "alternate" iso image. Mirroring the entire 12.10 bit takes about 12 gigs or so. I want to keep the local install server down to less than 1 gig. Any one have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's available from cdimage:

- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/quantal/
- http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/